# Move background image right

Tags: html, css

i am working on a project in which I have a background image all over the page and over that on the left half of it I have a div in which there is lots of content along with a slider.

The image is of a girl.

background image is in body tag and we cannot move it to another tag.
now the problem is that the background image is cut in half from the left due to that slider content. now we cannot see the girl's face, only her body
I have to move that image towards right so that we could see her face also
i tried to crop the free space from image but that didn't help and we cannot move the slider content.

Image size: 5MB
Resolution: 2710*4072
tried to do margin-right
padding-right
background-position:right
but i can't move that image an inch to right

```
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url('/2014/12/Profile-Background-image.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center right;
background-attachment: fixed;
line-height: 1;
```

Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/gmunish/dby4e86j/

Image is not visible so you can add your own image and check

Comment: please ad full url to your image

Comment: use postimage.org link for displaying image..and add image url..

Comment: seems working for me in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/dby4e86j/1/

Comment: @DCdaz saina G.L.P: thank you all for you assistance but I got the correct code from Pythonic

Comment: You got down-voted by people because of your lack of an image url.

Comment: the slider content was over the background image on the left side
the problem was that the slider content was cutting the background image in half and I wanted to move the background image to right. I had background-position: center right and I just had to add -50px to it so it would become center right -50px which move the background image 50 px towards it's right which solved my problem.
thank you all for your assistance

Comment: @DCdaz: I hate that and will remember to do it next time. but I got my answer that's what really matters to me. Anyways thanks for your time

Comment: and those who want to see the image, here is the link: http://postimg.org/image/41b55vbt9/

I didn't know how to share image links that's y i didn't do it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify how far from the right you want the background to be if that is useful.

for example if you wanted the image to be 50px *from* the right you could use:

```
background-position: center right 50px;
```

you could also use a negative value to move it further *to* the right like so:

```
background-position: center right -50px;
```

Comment: bro you are genius. 
but the correct code would be center right -50px
because +50px would move image towards left leaving a blank space of 50px on the extreme right
Issue resolved man.

Comment: Glad it worked. I updated the answer to show that you can offset in either direction.

Comment: If this helped you solve your issue it would be appreciated if you marked this as the correct answer.